# Custom filter in a custom page

Tags: magento2, customfilter

I have to create a custom filter on a custom page. Something like this reference site
https://visionfactorinstitute.com/courses
On clicking all - all data appear and on creating career development - relevant data appear

I have a CRUD module where I create new courses with category and subcategory. I want to achieve this functionality. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented anything for this one? How you currently get the courses collection here?

Comment: I have a custom collection

Comment: Yes but how you get that currently.